# Repeating calculation based on conditions

Tags: r, loops

What I am trying to do is pretty simple. However, I am new to R and have not learned much about loops and functions and am not sure what is the most efficient way to get the results. Basically, I want to count the number of rows that meet my conditions and do a division. Here is an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Main = c(0.0089, -0.050667, -0.030379, 0.066484, 0.006439, -0.026076), 
  B = c(NA, 0.0345, -0.0683, -0.052774, 0.014661, -0.040537), 
  C = c(0.0181, 0, -0.056197, 0.040794, 0.03516, -0.022662), 
  D = c(-0.0127, -0.025995, -0.04293, 0.057816, 0.033458, -0.058382)
)
df1
#    Main       B          C          D
# 1  0.008900   NA         0.018100  -0.012700
# 2 -0.050667   0.034500   0.000000  -0.025995
# 3 -0.030379  -0.068300  -0.056197  -0.042930
# 4  0.066484  -0.052774   0.040794   0.057816
# 5  0.006439   0.014661   0.035160   0.033458
# 6 -0.026076  -0.040537  -0.022662  -0.058382
```

My criteria for the numerator is to count the number of `B/C/D` that is `>0` when `Main` is `>0`; For denominator, count the number of `B/C/D` that is `!= 0` when `Main` is `!= 0`. I can use `length(which(df1$Main >0 & df1$B>0)) / length(which(df1$Main !=0 & df1$B !=0))` to get the ratios for each of the column individually. But my data set has many more columns, and I am wondering if there is a way to get those ratio all at once so that my result will be like:

```
#    B          C          D
# 1  0.2        0.6        0.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use apply:

```
 apply(df1[,-1], 2, function(x) length(which(df1$Main >0 & x>0)) / length(which(df1$Main !=0 & x !=0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this vectorized (No `apply` or `for` is needed):

```
tail(colSums(df[df$Main>0,]>0, na.rm = T) / colSums(df[df$Main!=0,]!=0, na.rm = T), -1)

#        B         C         D 
#0.2000000 0.6000000 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 1):

```
criteria1 <- df1[which(df1$Main > 0), -1] > 0
criteria2 <- df1[which(df1$Main != 0), -1] != 0
colSums(criteria1, na.rm = T)/colSums(criteria2, na.rm = T)
##         B         C         D 
## 0.2000000 0.6000000 0.3333333
```

Edit: It appears Niek's method is quickest for this specific data

```
# Unit: microseconds
#            expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#        Jim(df1) 216.468 230.0585 255.3755 239.8920 263.6870  802.341   300
# emilliman5(df1) 120.109 135.5510 155.9018 142.4615 156.0135 1961.931   300
#       Niek(df1)  97.118 107.6045 123.5204 111.1720 119.6155 1966.830   300
#     nine89(df1) 211.683 222.6660 257.6510 232.2545 252.6570 2246.225   300
#[[1]]
#          [,1]    [,2]     [,3]    [,4]
#median 239.892 142.462  111.172 232.255
#ratio    1.000   0.594    0.463   0.968
#diff     0.000 -97.430 -128.720  -7.637
```

However, when there are many columns the vectorized approach is quicker.

```
Nrow <- 1000
Ncol <- 1000
mat <- matrix(runif(Nrow*Ncol),Nrow)
df1 <- data.frame(Main = sample(-2:2,Nrow,T), mat) #1001 columns

#Unit: milliseconds
#           expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max
#       Jim(df1) 46.75627 53.88500  66.93513  56.58143  62.04375 185.0460
#emilliman5(df1) 73.35257 91.87283 151.38991 178.53188 185.06860 292.5571
#      Niek(df1) 68.17073 76.68351  89.51625  80.14190  86.45726 200.7119
#    nine89(df1) 51.36117 56.79047  74.53088  60.07220  66.34270 191.8294

#[[1]]
#         [,1]    [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
#median 56.581 178.532 80.142 60.072
#ratio   1.000   3.155  1.416  1.062
#diff    0.000 121.950 23.560  3.491
```

functions

```
Jim <- function(df1){
    criteria1 <- df1[which(df1$Main > 0), -1] > 0
    criteria2 <- df1[which(df1$Main != 0), -1] != 0
    colSums(criteria1, na.rm = T)/colSums(criteria2, na.rm = T)
}


emilliman5 <- function(df1){
    apply(df1[,-1], 2, function(x) length(which(df1$Main >0 & x>0)) / length(which(df1$Main !=0 & x !=0)))
}

 Niek <- function(df1){
     ratio1<-vector()
     for(i in 2:ncol(df1)){
         ratio1[i-1] <- length(which(df1$Main >0 & df1[,i]>0)) / length(which(df1$Main !=0 & df1[,i] !=0))
     }
     ratio1
 }

nine89 <- function(df){
    tail(colSums(df[df$Main>0,]>0, na.rm = T) / colSums(df[df$Main!=0,]!=0, na.rm = T), -1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be with a for loop that loops over the columns and applies the function that you wrote. Something like this:

```
ratio1<-vector()
for(i in 2:ncol(df1)){
ratio1[i-1] <- length(which(df1$Main >0 & df1[,i]>0)) / length(which(df1$Main !=0 & df1[,i] !=0))
}
```

Maybe there is a better way to do this with apply or data.table, but this is a simple solution that I can come up with. Works on any number of columns. Use `round()` if you want the answer in one decimal.